# jQuery ajax request - IE11 Access is denied

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

### The question

I'm making an ajax request via jQuery using the following function:

```
function ajaxRequest(requestName,responseFunction,parameters) {
 console.log('Making request ' + requestName);
 var now = new Date();
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ajax.php",
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ) {
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
    },
    success:function(msg) {
        console.log('Success! ' + msg);
    }
 });
}
```

What possible reasons for an 'Access is denied' error are there here? Is there anything I can do to get a more meaningful error message?

**More information...**

I'm currently calling this function to save a value in an input field. This works in all tested browsers.

I also call this function from an onpaste event (i.e. ), to do the same job, and this is what is failing, but only in IE11. The error is just "Access is denied.".

Note that this is not a cross domain request, it is requesting a file in the same directory.

Tested in:

- Mac + Safari
- Mac + Chrome
- WinXP + IE8
- Win7 + IE9
- Win 8 + IE10
- in 8.1 + IE11 (the only one that causes the problem.)

Note that I've stripped out some irrelevant parts of the code, such as using the responseFunction and parameters variable.

Comment: Is that the actual relative url?

Comment: Try it by adding below code -
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >`

Comment: epascarello - yes, that's what I've tested it with. Thanks for the suggestion WisdmLabs, that didn't make any difference though.

Comment: Make sure also that you are not loading your jQuery asset from a CDN such as Google Hosted Libraries. Because the domain is different, that violates certain security protocols that Microsoft uses to protect against Cross Site Scripting in Internet Explorer.

Another trial solution is change your jQuery version.

Comment: Thanks WisdmLabs - again all good ideas, but all ones I've tried :(

Comment: Have you validated the HTML?  Why?  Because invalid HTML forces IE into Compatibility Mode where strange things can/do happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of research, the only solution I could come up with that works, was to use a setTimeout to cause the AJAX request to trigger after 1 millisecond, instead of instantly. I presume this is some bug in IE11, but hopefully this solution will be useful to someone.

In the end, I changed this code:

```
ajaxRequest('save_function','response_function',params);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout( (function(params) {
    return function() {
        ajaxRequest('save_function','update_save_marksheet_mark',params);
    };
})(params),1);
```

Just to be clear, the first line of code worked in every browser tested, as far down as IE7, except for IE11.

Comment: How did you come up with this solution? Could you point to any other information?

Comment: Trial and error to be honest - because the error only occurred in a specific set of circumstances (IE, onPaste event), I figured that if I could just replicate it working as if it wasn't at the same time as an onPaste event it should work - and it did :)

Comment: Well it definitely fixed my problem!

Comment: Answer is also relevant for Windows 10. I had the same Problem with Windows 10 and IE 11. Your 'fix' was the only thing that worked.